# pandas dataframe plot barh color based on values not column

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Time": ['07/10/2022 08:22:44','07/10/2022 08:27:22','07/10/2022 08:27:44','07/10/2022 08:29:55','07/10/2022 08:33:14','07/10/2022 08:48:44'],
        "Sum":[50,5,10,20,5,30]
    }   
)
```

and I am trying to create a barh where the index would be set to `'Time'` and the color of the bars is based on the value `'Sum'`...I was thinking something like this:

```
df=df.set_index('Time')

colors=[]
for val in df['Sum']:
    if val <= 10:
        colors.append('green')
    elif val > 10 & val <=20:
        colors.append('orange')
    else:
        colors.append('red')
ax = df.plot(kind='barh',color=colors)
```

but all I'm getting is the color green. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean:  "for val in df['Sum']" instead of df2?

Comment: yes...fixing that. thanks

Comment: your code as is produces an all orange chart, so not sure how to help. Actually not as is since colors is not defined

Comment: Sorry...that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df=df.set_index('Time')
colors=[]
for val in df['Sum']:
    if val <= 10:
        colors.append('green')
    elif (val > 10) & (val <=20):
        colors.append('orange')
    else:
        colors.append('red')

plt.barh(df.index, df['Sum'],color=colors)
plt.show()
```

this will give you what you want. Carefull with the orange condition, you need to wrap in parenthesis to do the proper boolean check

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Series.plot` with `color` argument

```py
colors=[]
for val in df['Sum']:
    if val <= 10:
        colors.append('green')
    elif 10 < val <=20:
        colors.append('orange')
    else:
        colors.append('red')

# or
colors = pd.cut(df['Sum'].tolist(), [-np.inf, 10, 20, np.inf],
                labels=['green', 'orange', 'red'])


ax = df['Sum'].plot(kind='barh',color=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: the boolean check for orange is wrong

Comment: @Yuca Thanks, notice that when using another method to create `colors`

Comment: This looks great! But Yuca answered first and it's simpler to implement. Looks great tho!

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh then why show it? good answer tho

Comment: @Yuca Show what, don't understand.